# How to get an IP address that follows an arbitrary string with regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following input text:

`var k = "[NW_DST=10.10.1.1][DL_TYPE=IPv4][NW_SRC=10.10.6.2]"`

And I need to get the Ip address that is next to `NW_DST` using regexp. Here is what I tried but is not working at all.

`var src = k.match(/.*NW_DST=\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/);`

If I run that regex in http://regexpal.com/ it matches `[NW_DST=10.10.1.1` but if I run it on javascript it does not match anything.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/0s47u9r4/

Comment: Works for me too. Also, you could shorten your regex a tiny bit if you want - `/NW_DST=(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/`

Comment: very silly, I was missing '[0]'. Thanks guys!

Comment: If you're wanting just the IP, you need to use a [capturing group](https://eval.in/293952).